Pre-defined methods in Java
Is there a way in Java to set a "pre-defined" method, I don't know how to name it, otherwise I have search on Google. Let me explain with an example:
    class Class1 {
        public int getMyInt() {
            [...some calculations...]
            return <some number>;
        }
    }
    
    class Main {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
(*)     int a = 10 + c1;
    }

Clearly in line (*) there is a compilation error, I should write int a = 10 + c1.getMyInt(). My question is this: is it possible in Java to declare the getMyInt method a pre-defined method so that if I omit the method ina call, the compiler will just call that pre-defined method?

How should the compiler know what function you would like to call? AFAIK, Java does not support user-defined operator overloading.

No there isn't a way to do that.

Whoops, I regret re-opening this Question. On second reading, I realize this is indeed a question about operator overloading.  So it should be closed as a duplicate of this and this and more.

but this post IS NOT about operator overloading

No, this isn't possible in Java. If c1 refers to an instance of a class, it will always be parsed as a reference to that instance and not to a method of that class.

pzaenger, is there a way to put a keyword aka "public void predefined getMyInt..." or an annotation. BTW I am using Android Studio Jellyfish bundle with Gemini, it tells me to use the @Config annotation but I can't figure it out

@PhantomLord – Of course it WOULD be possible to "enhance" the Java language with that "predefined" keyword. But why? Just because you are too lazy to type the method you really want to be executed? I do not know whether such an extension was already considered in the past, but I can imagine very well why it was not implemented.

@tquadrat instead of insulting, why don't you give constructive criticism and give clarification? Maybe the best qualities of programming languages ​​don't require coincisiveness?
